# Using sigwait with std::thread and pipe

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals, posix, c++14

Consider a parallel program that consists of a number of worker threads. These threads have a `poll`-loop on some file descriptors. The program is supposed to run until ctrl-c is hit / the process receives a `SIGINT`. The program should never wake up unnecessarily.

I have devised the following combination of `sigwait`, `std::thread`, `pipe` and `pthread_sigmask`. Note that in the actual application, there are more file descriptors, hence I am not using atomics for shutting down the threads.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>

extern "C" {
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <poll.h>
}

int fds[2];

void thread_run() {
    struct pollfd pfd = {fds[0], POLLIN, 0};
    int ret = poll(&pfd, 1, -1);
    if (ret != 1) std::terminate();
    if (!pfd.revents & POLLIN) std::abort();
}

int main()
{
    int ret = pipe(fds);
    if (ret) std::abort();

    sigset_t ss;
    sigemptyset(&ss);
    sigaddset(&ss, SIGINT);

    ret = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, NULL);
    if (ret) std::abort();

    std::thread t(thread_run);

    int sig;
    ret = sigwait(&ss, &sig);
    if (ret) std::abort();

    char b = 0;
    ret = write(fds[1], &b, 1);
    if (ret != 1) std::abort();

    t.join();

    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
}
```

The program appears to work without any issues.

1. Is this approach conforming or am I overlooking any caveats?
2. Are there any specific error cases that might occur in regular operation
   and can be handled more gracefully?
3. Would the program be still correct if i swap `std::thread`-creation and `pthread_sigmask`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is a standard recommended approach and it works well. See examples section in [pthread_sigmask](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_sigmask.html).
2. Cannot spot any.
3. It would not be correct. Most signals are process-specific, which means they get delivered to any thread in the process that does not block that signal. Hence, that signal must be blocked in all threads but the one that handles the signal.

You may like to use `std::abort` call for unexpected situations. [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) *is called by the C++ runtime when exception handling fails*.

Comment: Just to clarify 3): Does this mean that there are indeed separate sigmasks per thread (and `pthread_sigmask` sets the current one), but they are inherited upon thread creation? Also thanks for the remark about `std::terminate`/`std::abort`!

Comment: Yes, each thread has its own signal mask, they are inherited from the creating thread, see [pthread_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html).